# Two layered canvas scaled to automatically fill flex column space

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, flexbox

I'd like two left canvas (layered on top of each other), to fit the left column (100% width minus the right column's 300px width).

It should work even if the canvas' height and width change dynamically, see here after 1 second and 3 seconds, when the canvas width changes from 500 to 1500 pixels wide.

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"), ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"), ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
setTimeout(() => {
    ctx1.canvas.width = 500;
    ctx1.canvas.height = 300; 
    ctx1.rect(0, 0, 500, 300);
    ctx1.fill();
    ctx2.canvas.width = 500;
    ctx2.canvas.height = 300; 
    ctx2.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx2.fill();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {
    ctx1.canvas.width = 1500;
    ctx1.canvas.height = 500; 
    ctx1.rect(0, 0, 1500, 500);
    ctx1.fill();
    ctx2.canvas.width = 1500;
    ctx2.canvas.height = 500; 
    ctx2.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx2.fill();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.container { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; }
.column { border: 1px solid black; }
.canvas-wrapper { margin: 1rem; flex: 1; }
#canvas2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
.right-column { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="canvas-wrapper column">
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column column">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how it should look like, in both cases it should be rescaled to fit the left column.
In the second case (with the red square), the canvas should be scaled down to fit in the left column (for example to a width of ~1000px if the browser viewport width is 1300 px, minus the 300 px for the right column), even if the real canvas width **is still 1500 px**.

[image]

I have tried multiple variations of `flexbox`, without success.

If possible, I'd like to keep `flex` and avoid `calc(100% - 300px)` rules.

**TL;DR: How to make two layered canvas of the same size on top of each other (this size can vary) fit automatically a column in a flex layout?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with FlexBox is to make the left column have a min-width:0, this allows it to shrink, and your 300px right column can then stay the same.

Also you will want to make another div for you canvas-wrapper, so that margins etc work as expected.

Eg.

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"), ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"), ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
setTimeout(() => {
    ctx1.canvas.width = 500;
    ctx1.canvas.height = 300; 
    ctx1.rect(0, 0, 500, 300);
    ctx1.fill();    
    ctx2.canvas.width = 500;
    ctx2.canvas.height = 300; 
    ctx2.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx2.fill();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {
    ctx1.canvas.width = 1500;
    ctx1.canvas.height = 500; 
    ctx1.rect(0, 0, 1500, 500);
    ctx1.fill();
    ctx2.canvas.width = 1500;
    ctx2.canvas.height = 500; 
    ctx2.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx2.fill();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.container { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
  background-color: yellow; 
}
.column { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
.canvas-wrapper { 
  margin: 1rem; 
  flex: 1; 
  position: relative; 
}
#canvas1 {
  width: 100%;
}
#canvas2 { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-column {
  min-width: 0;
}
.right-column {
  width: 300px; 
  min-width: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-column column">
        <div class="canvas-wrapper">
          <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
          <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column column">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does changing to grid help?

This snippet has two columns in the grid, the first one taking what's left after the 300px column. The width and height of the canvases is set to maximum of the cell dimensions.

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"),
  ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"),
  ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
setTimeout(() => {
  ctx1.canvas.width = 500;
  ctx1.canvas.height = 300;
  ctx1.rect(0, 0, 500, 300);
  ctx1.fill();
  ctx2.canvas.width = 500;
  ctx2.canvas.height = 300;
  ctx2.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx2.fill();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {
  ctx1.canvas.width = 1500;
  ctx1.canvas.height = 500;
  ctx1.rect(0, 0, 1500, 500);
  ctx1.fill();
  ctx2.canvas.width = 1500;
  ctx2.canvas.height = 500;
  ctx2.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
  ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx2.fill();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
  flex: 1;
}

#canvas2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.right-column {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="canvas-wrapper column">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column column">
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth, the max-width / max-height is doing the job indeed! Last thing: how would you automatically center the canvas vertically/horizontally inside the left column (like in my mockup screenshot)? This is probably doable without an extra flex/grid, but directly with your existing grid, is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried making canvas wrapper display flex and align-items: center for example?

Comment: Yes @AHaworth, but adding `display: flex; align-items: center;` to `canvas-wrapper` makes a bad positionning for the second wrapper (the one which should be layered exactly on the first one), do you see the same problem?